# How to find Mac OSX UID from Ubuntu

Tags: mount, users, macosx

How do you view Mac OSX user id without having to boot into OSX? I can mount the drive, but I can't find the UID for my user, which would hopefully enable me to access files without being root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer here. This is the UID that's tied to the user account.

According to [this article](http://www.defenceindepth.net/2011/09/cracking-os-x-lion-passwords.html), the user information can be found in this file

```
/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/{user-name}.plist
```

I verified and the UID was at the bottom of the file, in my case. There's also some business about a generateduid, but that's not what you want, so ignore that.

And to check ownership of the home folder, I used `stat /media/OSX/Users/someone`.

Answer (score 1):

Your non-sensitive user information is stored in the `/etc/passwd` file on your Mac OS just as in other *nix systems. *(This information is confirmed by [this link](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/mac/ch03_08.htm))*. So you could use the following steps to retrieve the UID of a user.

- Mount your Mac OS partition. In that look for a file called `passwd`
  in the `etc` folder of your Mac. In other words, open the
  `/etc/passwd` file of your Mac OS.
- Scroll and find your username
- The third number in the line corresponding to your username should be the UID of that user. For example, my username is `nits` and my UID is `1000` and my GID is `1000` too

  `nits:x:1000:1000:nits,,,:/home/nits:/bin/bash`

For more information on the `/etc/password` file, look into this blog post on [*nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)

Comment: That's helpful, but I found my answer elsewhere and, in my opinion, it's a little more helpful and complete (I would like to find the UID on my homefolder as well).

Comment: Cool :) Upvoted your answer, make sure you accept it by clicking on the tick-mark next to your answer :)